# Non-affine transformation with PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, transformation

I have a rectangular image (`O`) and I want to wrap it in a circle (`I`). Basically I want to take the two cartesian axis `x` and `y` and map them to polar coordinates `φ` and `r`, so that `I(φ,r) = O(f(φ),g(r))` being `f` and `g` linear functions.

I have found in PIL the `Image.transform` method, but as I read [the documentation](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm) this only works with affine transformation matrices.

**1. Can this "wrap a rectangle into a circle" be done with an affine transform?** I fear not.

**2. How else can I achieve this?**

Comment: You're going to have to write your own image processing code -- probably not in Python with or without PIL -- or use some other pre-written module that can do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

As according to martineau there is no such functionality in PIL, I had to implement it myself:

Being `overlay` the cartesian image and `circle` the polar image.

```
for x in range (800):
    for y in range (800):
        r = ( (x - 400) ** 2 + (y - 400) ** 2) ** .5
        phi = math.atan2 (float (y - 400), float (x - 400) )
        tx = int (phi * 1200.0 / 2.0 / math.pi + 300) % 1200
        ty = int ( (r - 100.0) * 350.0 / 250.0)
        if 100 < r < 350: circle.putpixel ( (x, y), overlay.getpixel ( (tx, ty) ) )
```